# laravel download excel file from s3 is not working

Tags: amazon-s3, laravel-5.1

I am using laravel 5.1 I need to download excel from amazon s3 storage. I done all process correctly and if it is pdf format file means it downloading correctly but for excel file download it is downloading zip format. Can please anyone help me to fix this issue.

```
$filePath = "CIS/download/format/upload_format.xlsx";
if ( Storage::disk('s3')->has($filePath)) {
$file = Storage::disk('s3')->get($filePath);
$getMimeType = Storage::disk('s3')->getMimetype($filePath);
return Response::make($file, 200, [
'Content-Type' => $getMimeType,
'Content-Disposition' => 'attachement; 
filename:upload_format.xlsx',
]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give your Content-Type as desired and Content-Disposition as 'attachment' because your files are coming from S3 and you have to download it as an attachment.

```
$event_data = $this->ticket->where('user_id', $user_id)->first();

$data  = $event_data->pdf;

$get_ticket = 'tickets/'. $data;
$file_name  = "YOUR_DESIRED_NAME.csv";

$headers = [
  'Content-Type'        => 'text/csv',            
  'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="'. $file_name .'"',
];

return \Response::make(Storage::disk('s3')->get($get_ticket), 200, $headers);
```